# IE8 What is tiggering beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue that is only a problem in IE8, go figure.

I have a anchor tag with an onclick attribute

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="foo();">Click Me</a>
```

and then foo is declared elsewhere:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
     function foo(){
       //do some work
       return false;
     }
</script>
```

After foo is called, my onbeforeunload handler is being executed, and I have no idea why.

I have had other instances, if the foo function does not return false, it triggers the beforeunload event in IE, but even with this function returning false, it still hits my onbeforeunload handler and I can't figure out why.

Is there any way to find out what is triggering it. I have viewed the event object inside my onbeforeunload handler, but it doesn't not seem to give me and relevant info.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to

```
<a href="#" onclick="return foo();">Click Me</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo();return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: The second method works. Can you explain why that is different then returning false at the end of the foo function?

Comment: Returning false cancels the click event and thus no refresh or the document unload. If the first one is not working, it would mean that foo is not returning false under some cases.

Answer (score 0):

There's also this thread over at microsoft "answers": http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie8-fires-onbeforeunload-when-clicking-a/0ac8cd9b-7483-4e16-b7c4-346df1f1499a
:)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well on some anchor tags that were being rendered by CK Editor.  Fixed by attaching a click event to a DIV that surrounded the anchor tags in question and stopped events from propagating to the window:

```
$('div.cke_form_fix').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```